# Azure Mobile Service Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm developing a windows 8.1 store app with Azure Mobile Services, and am trying to use the Unit Test Project for unit testing with AMS. But the testing method always ends with long waiting time and then process exit. My code used is like this:

```
namespace UnitTestLibrary1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
             "http://localhost:51543"
           );

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task TestMethod1()
        {
            var table = MobileService.GetTable<Place>();
            var query = await table
                .Take(100)
                .ToListAsync();
            var res = query.First();
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the recommended way for unit testing with Azure Mobile Service queries?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```html
   var query = await table
                .Take(100)
                .ToListAsync();
```

it will give you a list of places and not a query and by default the service retrieve up to 50 items per request.

Answer (score -1):

You do not want to call your actual service when testing it. This is really a very long topic to discuss but the following article will be a good starting point - [Unit Testing ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api) .

Usually, what you actually want to do is test the code that your web service is executing instead of testing the web service directly. That way your tests will be faster and more resilient.

Comment: He is doing integrated tests, That way it can simulate the requests like one  client application, but I believe best practice is to create unit tests and mocks to test controllers and so one....